# Problem with vertices after joining two objects

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, topology, boolean-modifier

I am relatively new to blender. I am trying to merge a rough lower torso to legs.

[image: Bad side]

I used a union Boolean modifier to join them. The topology where they connect is not great all around but one side is much worse than the other.

When I smooth shade I get these dark shadows along the edge where they were joined. I fixed it by recalculating my outside normals but it seems that my vertices are very messy along the seam.

[image: After recalculating normals. Messy vertices]

Can anyone tell me who to clean this up or if there is a simpler way of going about it?

Comment: Hello maybe you have inner faces, also, unless you plan to retopologize, the topology is not very good, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The boolean modifier doesn't tend to respect topology well. Especially for organic models like a character.

I would recommend:

1. Duplicating a separate mesh for the legs to keep the topology
2. Sculpting the new boolean union with dynamic subdivision or remesh
3. And then retopologize on top of the new sculpted mesh using snap to faces, or other retopologizing methods.